# What does "x.OnSpeak += (s, e)" mean?

Tags: c#, events

- I know that's the "e" for the event args, but what does "s" mean here and the "+= (  ,  ) =>" ?
- Is there's any other alternative implementations ?

  ```
  class Program
  {
   static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       var x = new Animal();
       x.OnSpeak += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("On Speak!");
       x.OnSpeak += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Cancel ? "Cancel" : "Do not cancel");

       Console.WriteLine("Before");
       Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

       x.Speak(true);
       x.Speak(false);

      Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
      Console.WriteLine("After");

      Console.Read();
     }

   public class Animal
   {
    public event CancelEventHandler OnSpeak;
    public void Speak(bool cancel)
     {
       OnSpeak(this, new CancelEventArgs(cancel));
     }
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: It's no longer ambiguous, i will accept the answer after a few minutes

Comment: This is a [`Anonymous Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) declaration.

Comment: `(s, e) => Console.WriteLine("On Speak!")` is a lambda. You might want to read up on lambdas in C#.

Comment: Thanks, That's also will help

Comment: @JLRishe It wasn't actually "ambiguous" in the technical, syntax related sense of the word. It was just unclear to the OP (and no longer is).

Comment: @JLRishe In case you didn't notice..I have a pretty nice amazing usefull answer down there which cleared the ambiguity FOR ME.

Comment: @Kinani I don't think you're really using the word "ambiguous" correctly, but ok, I see. I've gone ahead and clarified your ambiguous question title.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you, I hope you feel better now after letting me know.

Comment: @Kinani I sure do. I suggest you read the examples of good and bad question titles [here in the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This was definitely an example of a bad one. You clearly knew what you wanted to ask - it was the first line in your post and emphasized in bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often referred to as an "inline event", and is just another way of running particular code when the `OnSpeak` event fires.

```
x.OnSpeak += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("On Speak!");
```

The `s` is the `sender`, and the `e` is the event arguments.

You could rewrite your code like this, which may be more familiar-looking:

```
x.OnSpeak += OnSpeakEvent;

private static void OnSpeakEvent(object s, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("On Speak!");
}
```